# Problems installing Matlab via iso R2013a on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, software-installation, iso, matlab, dialog

I mounted the MATLAB for LINUX iso image to local drive and tried to  run ./install and a installation dialog box even appeared asking all the required details but when I pressed Finish to begin installation this error appeared

```
The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close. You may want to try re-installing your product(s). More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
```

and I have checked many forums and I couldnot get any posts regarding this sort of error. Please help.
Log file has

```
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) ##################################################################

(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) #
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) # Today's Date: 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Mon Feb 17 21:02:02 IST 2014
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) System Info
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) OS: Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Arch: amd64
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Data Model: 64
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Language: en
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Java Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_2354/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Java Version: 1.6.0_17
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Java Class Path: .
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) User Name: root
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Current Directory: /media/matlab
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) Input arguments: 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) root /media/matlab
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) tmpdir /tmp/mathworks_2354
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:02) standalone true
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:04) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:02:20) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:37:58) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
(Feb 17, 2014 21:38:26) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:01) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:05) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:05) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:48) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a

Products:
License Manager 11.11
MATLAB 8.1
Simulink 8.1
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.3
Communications System Toolbox 5.4
Control System Toolbox 9.5
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.3.1
DSP System Toolbox 8.4
Financial Toolbox 5.1
Fixed-Point Designer 4.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.17
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.2.3
Image Processing Toolbox 8.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.3
Mapping Toolbox 3.7
MATLAB Coder 2.4
MATLAB Compiler 4.18.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.0.1
Optimization Toolbox 6.3
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.2
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 1.2
Signal Processing Toolbox 6.19
SimEvents 4.3
SimMechanics 4.2
SimPowerSystems 5.8
Simscape 3.9
Simulink 3D Animation 6.3
Simulink Coder 8.4
Simulink Control Design 3.7
Stateflow 8.1
Statistics Toolbox 8.2
Symbolic Math Toolbox 5.10
Wavelet Toolbox 4.11

(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:51) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:93)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:58)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:82)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:26)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:51) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:55) Exiting with status -1
(Feb 17, 2014 21:41:55) End - Unsuccessful
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) ##################################################################
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) #
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) # Today's Date: 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Mon Feb 17 21:49:56 IST 2014
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) System Info
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) OS: Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Arch: amd64
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Data Model: 64
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Language: en
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Java Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_5054/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Java Version: 1.6.0_17
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Java Class Path: .
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) User Name: root
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Current Directory: /mnt
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) Input arguments: 
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) root /mnt
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) tmpdir /tmp/mathworks_5054
(Feb 17, 2014 21:49:58) standalone true
(Feb 17, 2014 21:50:00) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:50:16) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:50:35) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
(Feb 17, 2014 21:50:39) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:50:39) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 17, 2014 21:51:11) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a

Products:
License Manager 11.11
MATLAB 8.1
Simulink 8.1
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.3
Communications System Toolbox 5.4
Control System Toolbox 9.5
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.3.1
DSP System Toolbox 8.4
Financial Toolbox 5.1
Fixed-Point Designer 4.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.17
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.2.3
Image Processing Toolbox 8.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.3
Mapping Toolbox 3.7
MATLAB Coder 2.4
MATLAB Compiler 4.18.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.0.1
Optimization Toolbox 6.3
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.2
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 1.2
Signal Processing Toolbox 6.19
SimEvents 4.3
SimMechanics 4.2
SimPowerSystems 5.8
Simscape 3.9
Simulink 3D Animation 6.3
Simulink Coder 8.4
Simulink Control Design 3.7
Stateflow 8.1
Statistics Toolbox 8.2
Symbolic Math Toolbox 5.10
Wavelet Toolbox 4.11

(Feb 17, 2014 21:51:13) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:93)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:58)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:82)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:26)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Feb 17, 2014 21:51:13) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Feb 17, 2014 21:51:21) Exiting with status -1
(Feb 17, 2014 21:51:22) End - Unsuccessful
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) ##################################################################
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) #
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) # Today's Date: 
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Tue Feb 18 08:09:12 IST 2014
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) 
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) System Info
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) OS: Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Arch: amd64
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Data Model: 64
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Language: en
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Java Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Java Home: /tmp/mathworks_10230/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Java Version: 1.6.0_17
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Java VM Name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Java Class Path: .
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) User Name: root
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Current Directory: /mnt
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) Input arguments: 
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) root /mnt
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) tmpdir /tmp/mathworks_10230
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:12) standalone true
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:15) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:30) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 18, 2014 08:09:57) Default Installation Folder: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
(Feb 18, 2014 08:10:05) Starting local product/component search
(Feb 18, 2014 08:10:05) Completed local product/component search
(Feb 18, 2014 08:10:51) Confirmation Text: 
Installation folder:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a

Products:
License Manager 11.11
MATLAB 8.1
Simulink 8.1
Bioinformatics Toolbox 4.3
Communications System Toolbox 5.4
Control System Toolbox 9.5
Curve Fitting Toolbox 3.3.1
DSP System Toolbox 8.4
Financial Toolbox 5.1
Fixed-Point Designer 4.0
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox 2.2.17
Global Optimization Toolbox 3.2.3
Image Processing Toolbox 8.2
Instrument Control Toolbox 3.3
Mapping Toolbox 3.7
MATLAB Coder 2.4
MATLAB Compiler 4.18.1
Neural Network Toolbox 8.0.1
Optimization Toolbox 6.3
Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.2
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox 1.2
Signal Processing Toolbox 6.19
SimEvents 4.3
SimMechanics 4.2
SimPowerSystems 5.8
Simscape 3.9
Simulink 3D Animation 6.3
Simulink Coder 8.4
Simulink Control Design 3.7
Stateflow 8.1
Statistics Toolbox 8.2
Symbolic Math Toolbox 5.10
Wavelet Toolbox 4.11

(Feb 18, 2014 08:10:53) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:93)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:58)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:100)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:82)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.call(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:26)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Feb 18, 2014 08:10:53) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
(Feb 18, 2014 08:12:51) Exiting with status -1
(Feb 18, 2014 08:12:51) End - Unsuccessful
```

Comment: post the output of `cat /tmp/mathworks_root.log`.

Comment: I have edited the question to contain `cat /tmp/mathworks_root.log` for 5 times I tried doing this process of installing which failed.

Comment: there may be a chance of broken matlab file.